# D3.JS for Graphs in Angular: adding controller to app.js

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I'm looking to implement the following pieces of code into my angular boiler plate. I'm a bit new to the framework, so some patience is appreciated!

```
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <bars data="40,4,55,15,16,33,52,20"></bars>
</div>



  .chart {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 3px;
}

.chart div {
  width: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.chart div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #666;
}

angular.module('myApp', []).

   directive('bars', function ($parse) {
      return {
         restrict: 'E',
         replace: true,
         template: '<div id="chart"></div>',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           var data = attrs.data.split(','),
           chart = d3.select('#chart')
             .append("div").attr("class", "chart")
             .selectAll('div')
             .data(data).enter()
             .append("div")
             .transition().ease("elastic")
             .style("width", function(d) { return d + "%"; })
             .text(function(d) { return d + "%"; });
         } 
      };
   });
```

Which are the HTML, CSS and JS code excerpts for the graph only. I'm looking to implement this into my code, which is easy enough for the HTML/CSS (I've added a new div and style sheet in my header of my index.html).

I'm wondering how I would go about adding the JS bit of code to my app.js. My existing code already lists several modules, but no `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['zingchart-angularjs']);` type statement.

When I simply copy my code above in, I don't see any graph appear on my webpage.

Any help appreciated - thanks!

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: No error in console.